# Is it wrong not to wear a bra?

Tags: halacha, women, tznius-modesty

Is it a problem (for reasons related to tznius or any other Jewish concern) if a woman does not wear a bra?

Is it still a problem if it is not obvious that the woman is not wearing a bra? Women may wear different kinds of clothing to hide or reveal the fact that they're not wearing a bra.

Please answer with sources.

From the quote below, it seems to me that in some cultures it is not modest *not* to wear a bra, while in other cultures it is not modest *to* wear one.

What is the Jewish point of view on the modesty of different breast coverings?

The [Wikipedia article for Bra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra) says,

> [Some women] simply feel that bras improve their appearance. ... Some women wear bras because they want to conceal the natural shape of their breasts and nipples, responding to cultural standards of modesty, or because they fear criticism or unwanted attention.
>
> ...
>
> Depending on the social context, women may wear different kinds of clothing to hide or reveal the fact that they’re not wearing a bra.
>
> ...
>
> Some researchers have found health benefits for going braless.
>
> ...
>
> In October 2009, Somalia’s hard-line Islamic group Al-Shabaab forced women in public to shake their breasts at gunpoint to see if they wore bras, which they called “un-Islamic”. They told women that wearing a bra was deceptive and against Islamic teaching. Girls and women found wearing a bra were publicly whipped because bras are seen as “deceptive” and to violate their interpretation of Sharia law.

Comment: just an idea, maybe we consider it partially as clothing (if you wear outer clothing made of a thin material.) and partially as jewelry ((women use to were a string on their neck to appear fat (healthy, rich)) it will be not respectful if the queen of England will not wear it, (even if her outer clothing is made out of a thick material)),

Comment: Well... this question seems to have brought some new posters out of the woodwork...

Comment: @isaackotlicky but no solid answer

Answer (score -1):

Modesty has many aspects. Maybe you're asking if dressing immodestly because of feeling comfortable is better than 'modestly' for the world to see. In a way you're right since people notice when women are trying to show off or when they are trying to be comfortable, and for a normal person, the latter should be less attracting. However, you cant expect mainstream Judaism to accept this. Just for the unusualness of seeing women dressed causally causes interest and stares, so immodesty will continue to be defined as anything different from the usual.

Comment: So if it not noticeable there is no problem

Comment: @hazoriz I hope you're not assigning any significant weight to a random internet poster's musings.

Comment: @doubleAA i also do, but I am interested what is your opinion